# Permutation of the letters of the word CATERING which can be made given the stated constraints

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Example from the textbook:
[image]

Question:
[image]

Sorry people I know most of u are too smart for this question, but I really need help so for questions c, d, e and f I have solved already, but I don't think my method of solving them is correct. G is the one I struggled for hours.

info I already know
8 letters, 3 vowels (A,E,I) and 5 consonants (C,T,R,N,G)

**My Working Out**

for c, i did 3 x 4 x 5 x 4 x 3 which equals to 720 which is correct.

for d, i did (3 x 4) - (2 x 3) first which equals to 6 I then multiply it by 3, 2, 5, 4 together therefore the final answer is 720. See in the first part I multiply 3 (the number of vowels) by 4 the number of position as any of the three vowels can fit in any of the 4 spaces. The questions asks for two vowels, since 1 vowel is already in one space the second vowel has two of the 3 vowels to take from and any of the two vowels can fit into the 3 remaining spaces. I subtract, because my intuition tells me to do so.

for e, I did (3 x 4) - (2 x 3) - (1 x 2) first which equals to 4 I then multiply it by 3, 2, 1, 5 together, making the answer is 120 which is the right answer. Here, I follow the my own principle from d. So I'm not sure if I'm right.

for f, I got the total arrangements from question a minus the total amount of words without vowels. To get the words without vowels i found all four letter arrangement words with consonants only which is 120. 1680 (from a) - 120 = 1560 (Correct)

for g, I totally don't understand it, but the answer is 18 000.

Comment: It would help if you explained your reasoning.  Also, what is your background.  It looks like you have learned about the Multiplication Principle (also called the Rule of Product) and permutations.  Have you learned about combinations yet?  This is not a Pigeonhole Principle problem.

Comment: N.F. Taussig i haven't learnt combinations yet and apparently i don't need it to solve this question of mine, but i will learn it later soon. I have an example from the textbook that uses the pigeonhole way to solve a question similar to this one. i will edit the post to show you.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: By the way, which text are you using?

Comment: @PlsHelpMe which textbook is it ?

Comment: Sorry I know this is a bit late but, here you go: its called NewQMaths Nelson cengage learning.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers for parts c, d, e, and f are correct.  However, your reasoning for parts d and e is unclear.

> How many "words" can be made from the letters of the word CATERING using different permutations if two vowels and two consonants must be used without repetition?

We will select which vowels and which consonants will be used, then arrange them.  There are three ways to select two of the three vowels (decide which vowel to omit).  There are five ways to select the first consonant and four ways to select the second consonant.  However, this counts each selection of two consonants twice, once for each order in which we could have selected the same two consonants.  Therefore, there are
$$\frac{5 \cdot 4}{2} = 10$$
ways to select two of the five consonants to be in the "word".  Hence, there are $3 \cdot 10$ ways to select the two vowels and two consonants which will appear in the "word" and $4! = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$ ways to arrange the four distinct letters.  Thus, there are
$$3 \cdot 10 \cdot 4! = 3 \cdot 10 \cdot 24 = 720$$
permutations that can be formed by selecting two vowels and two consonants from the letters of the word CATERING without repetition.

> How many "words" can be made from the letters of the word CATERING using different permutations if three vowels and one consonant must be used without repetition?

We must use all the vowels. There are five ways to select which consonant will be used.  There are $4!$ ways to arrange the four selected letters.  Hence, there are
$$5 \cdot 4! = 5 \cdot 24 = 120$$
permutations that can be formed by selecting all three vowels and one consonant from the letters of the word CATERING without repetition.

> How many "words" can be made from the letters of the word CATERING using different permutations if at least two vowels and at least two consonants must be used without repetition in six-letter "words"?

Since there are only three vowels, there are two cases to consider, two vowels and four consonants or three vowels and three consonants.

Let's provide you with a strategy to implement.

Two vowels and four consonants:  Pick which two vowels will be used (how many ways can you omit one of the vowels?).  Pick which four consonants to use (How many ways can you omit one of the consonants?).  Arrange the six distinct letters you have selected.

Three vowels and three consonants:  You must use all three vowels.  Select which three of the five consonants you will use, keeping in mind in how many orders you could have picked the same three consonants.  Arrange the six distinct letters you have selected.

> The number of ways you can select three of the five consonants is $$\frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}$$ since there are five ways to pick the first consonant, four ways to pick the second consonant, and three ways to pick the third consonant. However, multiplying those numbers counts each unordered selection of three consonants six times, once for each of the $3! = 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$ orders in which you could have picked the same three consonants. This argument is more easily handled using [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), which is why I asked you whether you had learned them yet.